# Is it possible to customize the sharepoint Apps from the sharepoint Store?

Tags: sharepoint-server, apps-development, customization, sharepoint-store

Is it possible to customize the SharePoint apps from the SharePoint store? For example, there have lots of poll apps in the store, Is it possible to customize that app, If possible means, how can we move that changes from one server to another server. Please suggest me some best methods to achieve this.

Comment: not sure whether I got what you mean by customizing: before installing it and spread the once customized app to several servers?

Comment: Customize incense, Changing Graph result view, look and feel etc. Is there have any way to get that source code?  @Celophysis

Comment: I'd say this depends on the vendor / developer. If it is open source than yes, if it is Microsoft than no.